# Reference on Electronic volatility trading

Tags: option-pricing, volatility, market-making

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for a recommendation for a real life volatily trading book.](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1172/looking-for-a-recommendation-for-a-real-life-volatily-trading-book)

I recently came in contact with a quant desk that traded volatility. The discussion only highlited my lack of knowledge on the subject. I have not been able to find good references on the web.

I'm looking for information on the markets for listed options and tutorials, articles, books on the publicly known methods used to trade options (both market making an statistical arbitrage).

Comment: Sorry for not noticing earlier that this was already answered.  I'm just getting around to some overdue cleanup.

Answer (score 7):

[Volatility Trading](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470181990) by Euan Sinclair is a good book to get you started.